# Is table with 20,000 rows and 5 columns too large for Dissolve of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dissolve

Is a table with 20 000 rows and 5 columns too large for arc map 10.2.1?

I have tried several things without success to dissolve this table based on one feature.

The table was obtained from the union of a shapefile table with a .xls table.

I can't even export the table to .dbf. When I do this, the resulting table only shows the first line.

Is this a size problem?

Comment: 20,000 features shouldn't be a problem to dissolve _unless_ the features are very complex and therefore have a lot of vertices ([this blog post about so-called Godzilla features](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/07/23/dicing-godzillas-features-with-too-many-vertices/) explores that). If an export results in only one line, verify that there are no features currently selected (I've made that mistake frequently).

Comment: How exactly did you "union" a shapefile with a Excel file?  Did you change the row count or order while modifying the dBase file?  Did the original shapefile draw correctly?  How many vertices are in the average feature in the shapefile?  Of what topology class (point/line/polygon) is the table? Do you have a spatial index constructed? Please update the question with this information (vice answering in comments).

Comment: In principle this is not a large number of features. The bottleneck is usually the data format. I'll suggest that you first upload both your shapefile and excel data to a database. Even a filegeodatabase will give you a much needed boost in the performance.